# JavaFX, List to ObservableList to ListView

Tags: serialization, arraylist, javafx, dao, observablelist

So my problem is, that I have an serilized ArrayList and have to update it in my GUI to show its content in a ListView dynamically.
The serialization and deserialization works fine with the use of a DAO interface but the GUI won't refresh my ListView.

This class holds my data interaction (mostly save, load...):

```
public class Medienverwaltung implements Serializable, IDAO{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Medium> medienliste;
    public ObservableList<Medium> obList;   //public for test-reasons

    public Medienverwaltung(){
        medienliste = new ArrayList<Medium>();
        obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(medienliste);
    }

    //[...]

    public List<Medium> getMedienliste(){
        return this.medienliste;
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Here comes my GUI implementation snippet:

```
public class HauptFenster extends Application{

    private Medienverwaltung medienverwaltung;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        medienverwaltung = new Medienverwaltung();

        VBox root = new VBox();
        ListView<String> showliste = new ListView<String>();
        MenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar(stage);
        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        root.getChildren().add(showliste);

        //Make Listener and refresh the shown list!
        medienverwaltung.obList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Medium>(){
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Medium> change) {
                showliste.getItems().clear();
                for(Medium medium : medienverwaltung.obList){
                    //toString() is overwritten and works, too
                    showliste.getItems().add(medium.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        // this adds a Medium object to the Arraylist in Medienverwaltung
        medienverwaltung.aufnehmen(new Bild("Foto12", 2017, "Zuhause"));

        stage.setTitle("Medien Verwaltung");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 400) );
        stage.show();   
    }
    //[...]
```

I also tired to exchange the whole ArrayList from the class "Medienverwaltung" with an ObservableList, so that there is only one List remaining, which works for the GUI but not for the serialization and deserialization as I guessed before. (and tried a few other implementations)

Does anyone have an idea how to change my code so that it works?
And my second question is, what is the best way in terms of a 3 layer architecture?

*The following is a reference to Fabians Answer and responds to my comment on that*

**Update#1.1**  (addendum for explanation)

```
public interface IDAO {
    // Save method
    void speichern(List<Medium> liste) throws PersistenzException;
    // Load method
    List<Medium> laden() throws PersistenzException;
}
```

*Here comes my concrete save Method:*

```
@Override
public void speichern(List<Medium> medienliste) throws PersistenzException{
    File sfile = new File("medienliste.dat");

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sfile); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)){
        oos.writeObject(medienliste);
        System.out.println("Serialisierung erfolgreich!");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Serialisierung fehlgeschlagen!");
    }
}
```

**Update#1.2** (addendum for explanation)

```
//[...]  section of my GUI for saving
MenuItem speichern = new MenuItem("Speichern");
    speichern.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
            try{
        //Before:    medienverwaltung.speichern(medienverwaltung.getMedienliste()); -> doesn't work because of serializing an ObservableList
                medienverwaltung.speichern(medienverwaltung.getBackingList());
            }catch(PersistenzException pe){
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
//[...]
```

But as I guess, it's not a fine way to access the backinlist this way.

**Update#2:**

to respect the principle of encapsulation in a clean way I now added an overloaded Method in the class Medienverwaltung:

```
public void speichern() throws PersistenzException{
    speichern(backingList);
}
```

So my GUI now only calls speichern(). This actually calls the method for saving with the backedlist which is no more accessible from the outside. I hope this is no bad coding style ^^

BTW.: If you are reading this and have a similar problem, don't use **ObservableArrayList** for the synchronisation with a normal **List**, this won't work! Use **ObservableList** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the backing list (`medienliste`) from other classes by removing the getter. If you modify this list using the `ObservableList` the `ListView` (or every other object that has added a listener to the list) will properly update.

Furthermore unless `Medium` extends `Node` you can simply use this kind of object as items of the `ListView`, since the cells set the text to the result of the `toString` method called for the associated item by default.

```
public class Medienverwaltung implements Serializable, IDAO{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Medium> backingList;

    // transient field not persisted
    private transient ObservableList<Medium> medienliste;

    public Medienverwaltung(){
        backingList = new ArrayList<Medium>();
        medienliste = FXCollections.observableArrayList(backingList);
    }

    // make sure an ObservableList is created when reading the serialized object
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream inputStream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        inputStream.defaultReadObject();
        medienliste = FXCollections.observableArrayList(backingList);
    }  

    //[...]

    public ObservableList<Medium> getMedienliste(){
        return this.medienliste;
    }

    //[...]

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
    medienverwaltung = new Medienverwaltung();

    VBox root = new VBox();
    ListView<Medium> showliste = new ListView<>(medienverwaltung.getMedienliste());

    MenuBar menuBar = createMenuBar(stage);
    root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
    root.getChildren().add(showliste);

    // this adds a Medium object to the Arraylist in Medienverwaltung
    medienverwaltung.aufnehmen(new Bild("Foto12", 2017, "Zuhause"));

    stage.setTitle("Medien Verwaltung");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 400) );
    stage.show();   
}
```

Note that the `Medienverwaltung.aufnehmen` method should not work directly with the backing list - it should use the `ObservableList` instead to make sure changes can be observed...

---

**EDIT**

Looking at the `IDAO` interface it should probably be a object different to `Medienverwaltung`, since otherwise you'd violate the *seperation of concerns* design principle; also it wouldn't make sense to pass a value as parameter that's already contained as property of the object itself.

It seems that the `IDAO` object should be responsible for reading/writing the list data only which would make implementing `Serializable` with `Medienverwaltung` unnecessary. Probably something like this is expected solution to your excercise:

```
IDAO idao = new IDAOImplementation();
Medienverwaltung medienverwaltung = new Medienverwaltung(idao.laden());
```

```
public void handle(ActionEvent e){
    try{
        idao.speichern(medienverwaltung.getMedienliste());
    }catch(PersistenzException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
public Medienverwaltung(List<Medium> medien) {
    this.medienliste = FXCollections.observableArrayList(medien);
}
```

The `IDAO` implementation should most likely not depend on the implementation of the `List` and therefore not expect the `List` to be serializable. You can simply work around non-serialized lists by a) not using `ObjectOutputStream` to persist the data, but some other way not relying on serializable objects or b) simply copy the contents of the list to a serializable list:

```
@Override
public void speichern(List<Medium> medienliste) throws PersistenzException{
    File sfile = new File("medienliste.dat");

    try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sfile); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)){
        oos.writeObject(new ArrayList(medienliste));
        System.out.println("Serialisierung erfolgreich!");
    } catch(IOException e){
        throw new PersistenzException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, this works as far as possible. There is only one Problem remaining, I am not allowed to change the DAO interface (Yes, I should have mentioned that before -.-', sorry) and so I have still problems while serializing. From the DAO I get the following signatures: See Update#1.1
So I changed the call of my saving method in my GUI to the following: See Update#1.2
This works now, because I access the backinglist instead of the medienlist, but this is not a nice practice.
Is there a better way I didn't see yet?

Comment: Got everything correct and clean now I think.
[1.] wrote concrete DAO object class
[2.] transfered save/load methods to concrete DAO object class
[3.] gave concrete DAO to Medienverwaltung over the constructor, which takes place in an unconcrete DAO Reference (to make it exchangeable)
[4.] though I still use the backinglist, but only to give it to the DAO

So, thank you very much for helping me to improve my code, Fabian =D